# Can all reflexive verbs be used as reciprocal verbs?

Tags: gramática, verbos, reflexivos, verbo-pronominal

Can all reflexive verbs be used as reciprocal verbs and vice versa?

When I try to think of a sentence involving `each other` I can always reconstruct it using `myself` even if it isn't very logical.

Example:

> We got married to **each other**.
>
> I will marry **myself**.

When it comes to reflexive verbs and reciprocal verbs, I find that context doesn't help. Should I always use phrases like `uno al otro` or `sí mismo` or should I get used to them not being used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this one

> [suicidarse](http://dle.rae.es/?id=YfmGwPw)
>
> 1. prnl. Quitarse voluntariamente la vida.

I guess this is an example of a reflexive that can't be reciprocal, so this would be a counterexample for the "all reflexive verbs can be reciprocal" statement.

For the "all reciprocal verbs can be reflexive", I guess that if I can do it to others I should be able to do it to myself.

Of course, as you say in the question, you can always treat a reciprocal like a reflexive and viceversa if you don't really care about the meaning (Me caso conmigo mismo. Te suicido).

So, the answer to your questions could be a "probably yes, but as with every rule there's always a few exceptions".

Answer (score 1):

Not all - there are a number of verbs which have a subtle difference in meaning when used reflexively. Some examples:

#### Identical

- abanicar (to fan) / abanicarse (to fan oneself)

#### Subtle semantic difference

- acusar (to accuse) / acusarse (to confess)

#### Subject is object, but action is passive, not active

- aburrir (to bore) / aburrirse (to get bored)
- enojar (to anger) / enojarse (to get angry)
- entristecer (to sadden) / entristecerse (to get sad)
- rendir (to defeat) / rendirse (to surrender `"to be defeated"`)

#### Distinct

- abanar (to pay) / abanarse (to subscribe)
- comer (to eat) / comerse (to eat up)

#### Body parts

- peinar (to comb) / peinarse (to comb one's hair)
- cortar (to cut) / cortarse (to cut [one's hair, nails])
- quebrar (to break) / quebrarse (to break [a bone])

Comment: But many of those can still be used reciprocally, although it may require the addition of *los unos a lot otros* to make that interpretation clear.